# SQL Query with a Condition between 2 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-insert, sql-query-store

I'm trying to:

1) Find whether 1 object contains the same Username and Password that I have inputted, in Table 1

2) IF there is an object that contains the same Username and Password then

3) Carry out an INSERT statement inside Table 2.

So far the best I've got is:

```
(CASE WHEN table1 WHERE Username='myusername' AND Password='mypassword' 
    THEN ( INSERT INTO table2(things) VALUES('mythings') ) 
 ELSE Null END)
```

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: My server is a SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select the string to insert from `table1` and move the condition to the `where` clause. This way you have a statement that either inserts one record if the username and passowrd match, or no records if they don't:

```
INSERT INTO table2(things)
SELECT      'mythings'
FROM        table1
WHERE       Username='myusername' AND Password='mypassword'
```

Comment: this doesn't match the requirement "find whether 1 object..." - maybe add a `TOP 1` (though this still isn't entirely correct)

Comment: I'm making a (possibly false) assumption that the username and password combination is unique

Comment: Yes, the combination of each Username and Password is unique so really it will only contain 1 of itself.
I tried your suggestion but was given the error "#1241- Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: Is the SELECT portion correct? Would it not attempt to retrieve 'mythings' (the object i want to INSERT into table 2) from table 1?

Comment: @NickHarper yes, `'mythings'` is correct - it queries the literal you try to insert

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in a script or stored procedure use `IF`, e.g.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE Username='myusername' AND Password='mypassword')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2 VALUES('mythings')
END
```

Comment: The server I'm using won't allow me to use "EXISTS"

Comment: What server are you using? You have tagged the question with sql-server

Answer (score 0):

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tabel1 WHERE Username = @Username  AND Password= @Password))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Table2 Values(@Username,@Password)
    END
```

Comment: The server I'm using won't allow me to use "EXISTS"